# Zoom into country polygon with Leaflet with mouse click

Tags: leaflet, zoom

I have a GeoJSON file and I'm trying to create a click event to zoom into the specific country. I would also like to zoom out. So far the click events is not working, what am I doing wrong?

```
    // Creating map object
    var myMap = L.map("map", {
      center: [10.0522, -10.2437],
      zoom: 3
    });
    // Adding tile layer
    L.tileLayer("https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/light-v10/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}", {
      attribution: "© <a href='https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/'>Mapbox</a> © <a href='http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a> <strong><a href='https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/' target='_blank'>Improve this map</a></strong>",
      tileSize: 512,
      maxZoom: 18,
      zoomOffset: -1,
      id: "mapbox/light-v10",
      accessToken: API_KEY
    }).addTo(myMap);
    // Load in geojson data
    var geoData = "static/data/map.geojson";
    var geojson;
    // Grab data with d3
    d3.json(geoData, function(data) {
      // Create a new choropleth layer
      geojson = L.choropleth(data, {
        // Define what  property in the features to use
        valueProperty: "coordinates",
        // Set color scale
    scale: ["#ffffb2", "#b10026"],
    // Number of breaks in step range
    steps: 10,
    // q for quartile, e for equidistant, k for k-means
    mode: "q",
    style: {
      // Border color
      color: "#fff",
      weight: 1,
      fillOpacity: 0.8
    },
    // Binding a pop-up to each layer
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
      layer.bindPopup("Name: " + feature.properties.name + "<br>Nr Loans:<br>" + feature.properties.name);
    }
  }).addTo(myMap);
  markers.on("click", function (event) {
    // Assuming the clicked feature is a shape, not a point marker.
    map.fitBounds(event.layer.getBounds());
  });
  markers.addTo(map);
```

Comment: What is `markers` variable? I don't see it defined and filled with data in anywhere in the code. What is `L.choropleth`? Leaflet itself has no such object/method. Please edit your question and add missing info.

Comment: You're right, I'm still a newby on this and had several mistakes... I made it work now by changing markers to the correct variable "Layers" and the event had to be inside of "onEachFeature" as it is supposed to zoom when clicking in one of the polygons.